# Python String to Datetime format

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have an incoming data set where the time periods for data is in quarters i.e 4 quarters in a year. It is represented as as string ['2016:01:00', '2016:02:00','2016:03:00', 2016:04:00'] representing data for each quarter. How can I convert this to datetime format? My expected output for example will be 2016:01:00 for the first quarter of 2016. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the year and the quarter from your string and convert the quarter number into a calendar month.

```
from datetime import datetime


def convert_to_date(value):
    year, quarter, _ = value.split(":")
    return datetime(int(year), 3 * int(quarter), 1)


values = ["2016:01:00", "2016:02:00", "2016:03:00", "2016:04:00"]

list(map(convert_to_date,  values))
```